# PHP cUrl does not seem to post

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I am trying to Post a form with cUrl.

I am using PHP, but the site I want to post to is using aspx. I have been browsing the internet for solutions the past 2 days, and I think I came pretty far, but it’s still not working. I have got the hidden fields and the asp session id, and I also managed to send the relevant cookies. 
It’s not a https website, so no SSL verification needed, nor are there proxy servers or any form of authentication involved.

Curl does not return any errors.

After a manual post, the same page return with some additional information, which are the results I need. But with curl, the result is the same as the page with only the form. 
The page does require cookies, but I think I solved that issue because I do not get a notice about that anymore.

However, the firebug Net panel does not show any Post data. So maybe curl does not post anything?

Here is my code:

```
$fields = array(
        'ToolkitScriptManager_HiddenField' => '',
        '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
        '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewstate,          // when using urlencode() or rawurlencode(), i get message: Object moved to here, which links to an error page.
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventval,
        'scrollY' => 460
    );

    // get ASP.NET_SessionId from cookie file (need to do this because cookie file doen not contain AcceptCookie=Accept=True)
    // set the cookies we need
    // looks like we only need 2 relevant cookies: ASP.NET_SessionId and AcceptCookie
    $cookie_string = 'SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=64d9c94544d04fb6ac221265e99cb914; mf_user=1; __utma=66847866.1614717554.1414684101.1415373395.1415378138.6; __utmz=66847866.1414684101.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ';
    $cookie_string .= 'AcceptCookie=Accept=True; ' . 'ASP.NET_SessionId=' .getAspSessionidFromCookiefile($cookies) . ';';

    var_dump($cookie_string);

    curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);      // can be passed as array or not ??
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0");
//    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: text/html;',
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                                            'Host: www.website.com'
                                            ));
//    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
//    curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
//    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);     // gives notice 'this site requires cookies'
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_string);     // no notice, but still not get the result page
//    $cookie = 'SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=64d9c94544d04fb6ac221265e99cb914; mf_user=1; __utma=66847866.1614717554.1414684101.1415373395.1415378138.6; __utmz=66847866.1414684101.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); AcceptCookie=Accept=True; ASP.NET_SessionId=hz3yt4blbfaiv2eyd4zds155;';
//    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);      // no notice about cookies, but cookie content probably not good, so try to rewrite cookie data as string


    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo 'Error: ';
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));      // returns: Error: string(0)
    echo ' - Code: ';
    var_dump(curl_errno($ch));      // returns: Code: int(0)
    echo ' - curl getinfo: ';
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch),true);
    echo ' result = <br/><br/><br/>';
    var_dump($result);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but I highly recommend you check out the Unirest PHP library, it makes handling things like GET, POST and PUT much easier in PHP... http://unirest.io/php.html

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, I will look into it. But they not have much documentation, do you know if it supports cookies?

Comment: Unirest uses curl too, and does not support cookies. Of course I can tweak the code a little, but that would be the same as writing my own code.